# Passing Firebase database reference data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to pass an array that contains user info pulled from Firebase from one controller to another using a segue. I'm able to do it when everything is in a tableview, but not when it's in a regular controller view. Can someone help plz?

**View Controller**

```
var userArray = [User]()

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showGuestView" {
        let guestVC = segue.destination as! GuestUserViewController
             guestVC.ref = userArray.ref //this would work using userArray[indexPath.row].ref if it was a tableview
             //ref represents DatabaseReference?
        }
    }

 DatabaseClass.fetchUser() { (user) in
    if let user = user {
       self.userArray.append(user)
 }
```

**Database Class**

```
func fetchUser(completion: @escaping (User?)->()){

    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!

    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("getinfo").child(currentUser.uid)

    postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for childSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let request = childSnapshot.key
            let userRef = self.databaseRef.child("users").child(request)

            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (currentUser) in

                let user: User = User(snapshot: currentUser)
                completion(user)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

**User Structure**

```
struct User {

    var firstname: String!
    var uid: String!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    init(firstname: String, uid: String){        
        self.firstname = firstname          
        self.uid = uid            
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()           
    }

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){

        if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {               
            self.firstname = snap["firstname"] as! String
            self.uid = snap["uid"] as! String         
        }   
        self.ref = snapshot.ref
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any]{
        return ["firstname":self.firstname, "uid":self.uid]
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if more info is required!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see `userArray` is an array of users, hence you could not use `userArray.ref` because the array doesn't have any property like `ref` in its definition. In the table view, it is working because you pulled a `user` object and then passed `ref`.

Try to get a selected user instance before passing to the guest view controller.

```
let user =  userArray[selected user index];
guestVC.ref = user.ref
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question, but how do I do that? The structure of my userArray is: [User(firstname: "Mike", uid: "1")] and I just want to retrieve the uid

Comment: How you have put users into array? Would you share these code?

Comment: Sure! I added additional info in the question

Comment: @johnsmith, you must iterate `userArray` to access properties from `User` object. For example: `for user in userArray {
   print("User uid: " + user.uid)
  }`